# FactoryGirl - How to dynamically generate, or override a callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot

I have an application with archive functionality, allowing users to restore objects after they are deleted.

- An `Organisation` `has_many` `Contact`s, and must have at least one.
- A `Contact` must `belong_to` a single `Organisation`
- Both objects can be archived, however an `Organisation` is only `archived` when all of its associated `Contact`s are archived.

Currently I have the following. The problem with this approach is that `FactoryGirl.create(:archived_organisation)` appears to trigger both of the `after(:create)` callbacks in the `:organisation` factory:

```ruby
factory :contact do
  name { Faker::Name.first_name }
  association :organisation, :factory => :organisation, :contacts_count => 0

  factory :archived_contact do
    archived true
    association :organisation, :factory => :archived_organisation, :contacts_count => 0
  end
end

factory :organisation do
  name { Faker::Company.name }

  ignore do
    contacts_count 2
  end

  after(:create) do |instance, evaluator|
    FactoryGirl.create_list(:contact, evaluator.contacts_count, organisation: instance)
  end

  factory :archived_organisation do
    archived true

    after(:create) do |instance, evaluator|
      FactoryGirl.create_list(:archived_contact, evaluator.contacts_count, organisation: instance)
    end
  end
end
```

How should this be achieved? Is it possible to override the `:organisation` `after(:create)` callback in the `:archived_organisation` factory? If not, is it possible to dynamically generate the callback based on which factory is being created?

Hopefully I'm missing something obvious, but I'm welcome to suggestions that I should be going about this a different way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
after(:create) do |instance, evaluator|
  unless instance.archived
    FactoryGirl.create_list(:contact, evaluator.contacts_count, organisation: instance)
  end
end
```

Comment: Aah should have thought of that. It worked perfectly. Thanks. :)